# Efficient way to handle multiple imports in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

So I am developing a site on React and trying to organize BrowserRouter, so for every component(page) I create a path in App.js like this

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
<Route path="/about" component={About} />
```

and I would like to add multiple components to create multiple routes like that. The question is, is there an efficient way to handle multiple imports from ONE folder that contains only .js files. I have a folder "./articles" and for every single file I want to export I do this now

```
import MyComponent1 from "./articles/MyComponent1.js";
```

Repeating this line only changing the last parameter doesn't seem right. Is there a trick for import that can make it more efficient?

Answer (score 7):

If you want, you could make an index.js file in articles who's sole job is to collect the various components and export them from a single location. For example:

```
// /articles/index.js

export { default as MyComponent1 } from './MyComponent1.js';
export { default as MyComponent2 } from './MyComponent2.js';
export { default as MyComponent3 } from './MyComponent3.js';
export { default as MyComponent4 } from './MyComponent4.js';

// Used in another file:

import { MyComponent1, MyComponent2, MyComponent3, MyComponent4 } from './articles';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `index.js` file into the `/articles` directory and let that `index.js` file import and export all classes in the folder. Afterwards you can import all of the exports from the same path.

Comment: yeah, I know about this one. but if you have hundreds of articles, and your project is written with React, does that mean all of them have to be imported like that, manually? like there's no dirty hack with * or something? I mean my project is not that big, but I'm still curious. I'm just a newbie trying to figure things out:)

Comment: @justreacting i don't think that you can import from different files with just using smth like `*`. But you could at least write a script which reads your filenames and generates that import / export code dynamically. But this will only work if there is only one export per file and if the filename equals the class to be exported

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this situation with node js (emulate `import *`):

- You need read folder with `fs.stat` library with your components
- You need get list of the files in array
- Then dynamically create router.js `fs.writeFile` file with all of this components
- After file was placed, your webpack fetch file again and then rebuild
  your bundle with many imports

Answer (score 0):

If articles are different only by its content, but the structure is the same, I would suggest creating just one general 'Article` component that will show different stuff based on provided props and you can store the info of the article in some JSON or backend in some array and iterate over that. That will allow you to write the code once and just populating the array of articles with no need to maintain imports. Hope this helps!